# React input field not adding to the already rendered list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, rendering

I have been trying to add an option to the food list to add other foods with an input field. Every time I hit enter, it takes away not only the input field but it also takes away the food list. I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly here.

Here is my search bar component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SearchBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            inputValue: ''
        }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.addItem = this.addItem(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const inputTerm = event.target.value;
        this.setState({
          inputValue: inputTerm
        })
        console.log(this.state.inputValue)
    }

    addItem(props) {
        const food = this.props.food;
        food.push(this.state.inputValue)
    }


    render() {
        return (<div>
            <form
              className="form"
              onClick={this.addItem}>
              <div className="edit-input-div">
                <input type='text' value={this.state.inputValue}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  className='form-control'
                  placeholder="AddItem"
                />
                <span> 
                  <button onClick={this.addItem} className="add-new-item">Add Food</button>
                </span>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

it is being rendered here:

```
import React from 'react';
import shortid from 'shortid';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';

const TotalListItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <ul className="cook-list" id={props.index}>
            {props.food.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <li className="cook-list-items" key={shortid.generate()} id={index}>{item.title}</li>     
                )
            })}
        <button className="delete" onClick={() => props.onDelete(props.food)}>Delete Order</button>
        <button className="complete" onClick={() => props.onComplete(props.food)}>Complete Order</button>
        <SearchBar 
            food={props.food}
        />
        </ul>
    );
};

export default TotalListItem;
```

which is being rendered here:

```
import React from 'react';
import shortid from 'shortid';
import TotalListItem from './TotalListItem';

const Total = (props) => {
    if (props.cookList.length === 4) {
        alert('the manager has been alerted')
    }

    const renderProps = props.cookList.map((food, index) => {
        return (
            <TotalListItem
                index={index}
                food={food}
                key={shortid.generate()}
                onDelete={props.onDelete}
                onComplete={props.onComplete}
            />
        );
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <div>{renderProps}</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Total;
```

Comment: The first thing I notice in `SearchBar` component is that you're trying to add value to the props (wrong approach). Always remember "Props down, event up"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the data passed to your component through props. Your addItem method in your SearchBar component tries to add an item to the food props which is receives from its parent. This is causing the add to fail.

Instead, create a method in the parent component which does the same thing to the actual food array and pass it to the SearchBar component via its props. This should hopefully solve your issues.

Something similar to the class below.

```
export default class SearchBarParent extends React.Component{
   constructor{props){
     super(props);
     this.state={food:[]};
....
     }

   addItem=(item)=>{
     let foodList = [...this.state.food];
     foodList.push(item);
     this.setState({food:foodList});
     }
...
    render(){
     return(
          <SearchBar food={this.state.food} addItem={this.addItem}/>
     ...
     );
   }

}
```